# Is it true that $I \operatorname{Hom}_R (M,N) = \operatorname{Hom}_R (M,IN)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $I$ be an ideal and $M,N$ be $R$-modules.

It is almost trivial that $I \operatorname{Hom}_R (M,N) \subseteq \operatorname{Hom}_R (M,IN)$,
but I find difficult to show the opposite direction.

Is this statement generally true? If it isn't, then can it be made true by adding several conditions? ($R$ is Noetherian, $M,N$ are finitely generated, etc.)

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$If both $M, N$ are finite free this holds, because both $I \Hom(M, N)$ and $\Hom(M, IN)$ can be thought of as the set of matrices with entries in $I$. Similarly, if $M$ is finite free and $N$ is finite, I think you obtain the result by choosing a surjection $\pi: R^n \to N$ and lifting $\phi: M \to IN$ to $\psi: M\to IR^n$. Then $\psi = \sum_i a_i \psi_i$ with $a_i \in I$ by the previous step, and so $\phi=\sum_i a_i(\pi\circ\psi_i)\in I\Hom(M,IN)$. I think if $M$ is not free, you would have to descent the $\psi_i$ to $M$, which does not always work?

Comment: @red_trumpet Yeah, that was a silly mistake. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Let $R=k[x,y]$, $M=k[x,y]/(y^2)$, $N=k[x,y]/(y^3)$, $I=(y)$. This is a counterexample